# PHP multilevel JSON decode

Tags: php, json

I try to read IME field in PHP from following JSON FORMAT:

```
{"komentarji": [ {"RC_KOMENTARJI": [ {
          "K_ID": 101,
          "STATUS": "A",
          "IME": "boris",
          "E_MAIL": "test@example.com",
          "KOMENTAR": "testni vnos",
          "IP": "10.0.0.6",
          "DATUM_ZAPISA": "2016-12-03T23:23:47Z",
          "DATUM_UREJANJA": "2016-12-03T23:24:01Z"
        },
        {
          "K_ID": 1,
          "STATUS": "A",
          "IME": "Peter",
          "KOMENTAR": "Zelo profesionalno ste opravili svoje delo.",
          "IP": "10.0.0.8",
          "DATUM_ZAPISA": "2011-05-04T00:00:00Z"
        }
      ] } ] }
```

How can I reach that field via foreach in PHP? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

Let you decode the json to object named `$result`.

If you want to read first IME then try this

```
$result->komentarji[0]->RC_KOMENTARJI[0]->IME
```

If you want to read all IME then you have to apply loop throw `komentarji` and `RC_KOMENTARJI`

Answer (score 0):

Decode it by using json_decode().

```
$object = json_decode($json);
// result in object
$array =  json_decode($json, true);
// result in array
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($array['komentarji'] as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value['RC_KOMENTARJI'] as $k => $val) {
        echo $val['IME'] . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

This will print:

```
boris
Peter
```

Hope it helps!!!